# Use page variable as template variable

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I currently have a simple infobox template running on an internal mediawiki. I would like to pass the pages category to the template so that i can generate a list using category tree.

Is it possible to have the template pick up Category = foo

from my pages that already have
`[[Category:Foo]]`

written on them?

i.e my template text at the top of the page would have a section like

```
{{Infobox website | Category = *something* }}
```

to pick it up from `[[Category:Foo]]` that I already have on all of my pages?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in [Magic Word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) for getting the categories, but you could easily create a [parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions) for that, and use the output with e.g. the [Arrays extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays) to find out if a page is in a certain category or not. However, this seems like a lot of work to save very little work (typing a few extra letters once in a while).

If you want to create a parser function to get the current it is as simple as this:

```
function getCategories( &$parser, $title) {
    // Will return a comma separated list of categories.
    $categories = $title->getParentCategories();
    return implode(",", $categories);
}
```

If you know what categoery to check for for each page, you could also use [Extension:PageInCat](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageInCat).

**Edit:** I see now that your question is tagged `Semantic MediaWiki`. That makes it simple:

```
{{#if:
  {{#ask:[[Category:Foo]] {{FULLPAGENAME}}|default=|}}
  |''This page is in Category:Foo!''
  |''This page is not in Category:Foo. Let's add it.''
}}
```